# Unity how to do every Android build as a separate application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a mobile game with `Unity` for `Android` and I want each build I make to be considered a new application. Now, to install a new test build, I have to delete the previous one. But I need to have **both an old and new versions on the phone** so that I can quickly switch between them without reinstalling. Is it real, can someone give a short guide on how to do it, please?

Comment: can't you just use a different name? Like just append an increasing index or something

Comment: Tried it, doesn't help. Either it rolls over the previous one, or the installer writes “failed to install” and I have to delete the old version.

Comment: I was referring to the `PlayerSettings` -> `Product name` .. afaik if you change the product name it should also use a different Application ID

Answer (score 0):

Change the application name and bundle identifier in the project settings, not just the built application file.